# SELECT DISTINCT ON, ordered by another column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, order-by, greatest-n-per-group, distinct

Please consider the following table `test`:

```
CREATE TABLE test(col1 int, col2 varchar, col3 date);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1,'abc','2015-09-10')
, (1,'abc','2015-09-11')
, (2,'xyz','2015-09-12')
, (2,'xyz','2015-09-13')
, (3,'tcs','2015-01-15')
, (3,'tcs','2015-01-18');
```

```
postgres=# select * from test;
  col1 | col2 |    col3    
 ------+------+------------
     1 | abc  | 2015-09-10
     1 | abc  | 2015-09-11
     2 | xyz  | 2015-09-12
     2 | xyz  | 2015-09-13
     3 | tcs  | 2015-01-15
     3 | tcs  | 2015-01-18
```

I'd like to have a returned set ordered by date desc:

```
 col1 | col2 |    col3    
------+------+------------
    2 | xyz  | 2015-09-13
    1 | abc  | 2015-09-11
    3 | tcs  | 2015-01-18
```

What I've managed to accomplish with `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (col1) col1, col2, col3 from test order by col1, col3 desc;
 col1 | col2 |    col3    
------+------+------------
    1 | abc  | 2015-09-11
    2 | xyz  | 2015-09-13
    3 | tcs  | 2015-01-18
```

And not what I need with `having`:

```
select distinct on (col1) col1, col2, col3 from test group by col1, col2, col3 having col3 = max(col3)
 col1 | col2 |    col3    
------+------+------------
    1 | abc  | 2015-09-10
    2 | xyz  | 2015-09-13
    3 | tcs  | 2015-01-18
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can still use `DISTINCT ON`. Just wrap it into an outer query to sort to your needs. See:

- [Get distinct on one column, order by another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302068/939860)
- [PostgreSQL DISTINCT ON with different ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9796104/939860)

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1)
          col1, col2, col3
   FROM   test
   ORDER  BY col1, col3 DESC
   ) sub
ORDER  BY col3 DESC, col2;
```

Assuming that `col2` functionally depends on `col1`, so we can ignore it in `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` of the inner query. But I added it to the outer `ORDER BY` as meaningful tiebreaker. If `col2` not unique without `col1`, you might append `col1` additionally.

Assuming `col3` is defined `NOT NULL`. Else append `NULLS LAST`:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

With only ***few*** rows per `(col1)`, this is **typically the fastest solution**. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a164169437ed62b6cffc378132f16eae&hide=3)*

A subquery with the window function `row_number()` (like 
Vérace suggested) is a valid alternative, but typically slower. I have done [many tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860), but try yourself. It has to sort twice, just like `DISTINCT ON` (which may switch to a hashing algorithm internally if that's expected to be faster), but it keeps all rows after the inner query, adding needless cost. Either way, you don't need `ORDER BY` in the inner query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM  (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3
       ,  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS rn
   FROM   test
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY col3 DESC, col2;
```

And don't use a CTE if you don't need it. It's typically considerably more expensive (up until Postgres 12, where this was fixed, mostly).

For ***many*** rows per `col1`, indexing becomes much more important, and there are typically **much faster alternatives**. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Aside, unlike Oracle or SQL Server, PostgreSQL does not use the term "analytic functions" for [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). (What's "analytic" about those functions?)

Answer (score 8):

This is a classic [`greatest-n-per-group`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. They frequently arise in a whole host of areas and, like [`Window functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html) (see below) are well worth studying.

Nowadays, it is typically solved by using Wimdow (aka Analytic) functions - see the fiddle [`here`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ad6dff9ea0dc870c900dd4e1a05ef616).

You can use this query -

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS rn,
    col1, col2, col3 
  FROM test
  ORDER BY col3 DESC
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Result -

```
rn  col1    col2    col3
1   2   xyz     2015-09-13
1   1   abc     2015-09-11
1   3   tcs     2015-01-18
```

Window functions are well worth getting to know - they are very powerful and you will find that they will repay you many times  for any effort you put into learning them. Run the inner query on its own - experiment, it's how I learnt. BTW, it's always worth tagging your question with the version of PostgreSQL that you are using!

A more traditional method of doing this would be

```
SELECT x, y, mc FROM
(
  SELECT col1 AS x, col2 AS y, MAX(col3) AS mc
  FROM test
  GROUP BY col1, col2
) AS tab
ORDER BY mc
```

Same result - also on the fiddle.