# Sum all unique values from previous dates

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, sum, distinct, running-totals

Let's say, for simplicity sake, I have the following table:

```
id      amount     p_id     date
------------------------------------------------
1       5          1        2020-01-01T01:00:00
2       10         1        2020-01-01T01:10:00 
3       15         2        2020-01-01T01:20:00 
4       10         3        2020-01-01T03:30:00 
5       10         4        2020-01-01T03:50:00 
6       20         1        2020-01-01T03:40:00
```

Here's a sample response I want:

```
{
 "2020-01-01T01:00:00": 25, -- this is from adding records with ids: 2 and 3
 "2020-01-01T03:00:00": 55  -- this is from adding records with ids: 3,4,5 and 6
}
```

I want to get the total (`sum(amount)`) of all unique `p_id`'s grouped by the hour.

The row chosen per `p_id` is the one with the latest `date`. So for example, the first value in the response above doesn't include `id 1` because the record with `id 2` has the same `p_id` and the `date` on that row is later.

The one tricky thing is I want to include the summation of all the `amount` per `p_id` if their `date` is before the hour presented. So for example, in the second value of the response (with key "2020-01-01T03:00:00"), even though `id 3` has a timestamp in a different hour, it's the latest for that `p_id 2` and therefore gets included in the sum for "2020-01-01T03:00:00". But the row with `id 6` overrides `id 2` with the same `p_id 1`.

In other words: always take the latest `amount` for each `p_id` so far, and compute the sum for every distinct hour found in the table.

Comment: *"2020-01-01T03:00:00": 55 #this is from adding records with ids: 3,4,5 and 6* Why row #3 is taken (its datetime is earlier then specified in your responce)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple case

Getting the sum **for a single, given hour** is relatively simple:

```
SELECT timestamp '2020-01-01 03:00:00', sum(amount)
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (p_id) amount
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  date < timestamp '2020-01-01 03:00:00' + interval '1h'
   ORDER  BY p_id, date DESC
   ) sub;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is typically substantially faster than subquery / CTE with `row_number()`. See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT ON, ordered by another column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266559/select-distinct-on-ordered-by-another-column/266568#comment524902_266568)

For *many* rows per `p_id`, there is potential to optimize some more with smart indexing and a corresponding query. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

#### Special running sum for every hour

You seem to want the sum **for every distinct hour in the table**.

You can simply distill distinct hours, and apply the simple solution to ever one of them in a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
WITH grid AS (  -- or some other source?
   SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('hour', date) AS hour
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT *
FROM   grid
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT sum(amount)
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (p_id) amount
      FROM   tbl
      WHERE  date < grid.hour + interval '1h'
      ORDER  BY p_id, date DESC
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
ORDER  BY grid.hour;
```

Should be fine while there are not *many* distinct hours. But the query **does not scale very well**. The latest `amount` for every `p_id` is computed at full (steadily increasing) cost for every additional hour.

#### Optimize running sum for many hours

I expect this recursive CTE to scale better (while having considerable overhead initially), as it only needs to join to one row per `p_id` for every next hour:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  values AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (1, 2)
          date_trunc('hour', date) AS hour, p_id, amount
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY 2, 1, date DESC  -- !
   )
, hours AS (
   SELECT hour, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY hour) AS hnr
   FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT hour FROM values) sub
   )
, cte AS (
   SELECT p_id, h.hour, v.amount, 2 AS next_hnr
   FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT p_id FROM values) i  -- all IDs
   JOIN   hours       h ON hnr = 1             -- first hour
   LEFT   JOIN values v USING (p_id, hour)

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.p_id, h.hour, COALESCE(v.amount, c.amount), c.next_hnr + 1
   FROM   cte         c
   JOIN   hours       h ON h.hnr  = c.next_hnr
   LEFT   JOIN values v ON v.p_id = c.p_id
                       AND v.hour = h.hour
   )
SELECT hour, sum(amount)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Plus, there may be more potential to optimize, depending on value distribution, like indicated for the simple case at the top.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=493bfdcc64b10d05866b148e779a6ca4)*

Aside: calling your `timestamp` column "date" is rather misleading as that is a different basic data type.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer. Your last query seemed to work. I know this wasn't included in the OP, but what if instead of adding the amount from the latest `p_id` I want to add from the latest `p_id`, `loc_id`(not included in original table) pair. I tried changing `(SELECT DISTINCT p_id FROM values)` to `(SELECT DISTINCT p_id, loc_id FROM values)` but it made no difference to the answer.

Comment: @tony: To extend the logic with `loc_id`, you need to adapt the code in several positions. I suggest you ask a new question. You can always link to this one for reference (and drop a comment here to link back).

Comment: will do, thanks!

Comment: Basically, this: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f2d3bcd1e0b441f0428db039f2bc78c7)*. BTW, did you compare performance of the 2nd and 3rd query?

Comment: I'm not currently in a position to work with large datasets but when I do (hopefully soon), I will test and report my results... Thanks for the new query in fiddle, I appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 1):

Look for

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
              FROM source_table
              WHERE date_trunc('hour', date) = @needed_datetime_truncated_to_hour )
SELECT @needed_datetime_truncated_to_hour, SUM(amount)
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```